# Canonical question+answer about direct ethernet connection PC Windows <-> headless RPi?

Tags: discussion

After years of raspberrypi-ing, I randomly found a much easier way to connect PC Windows <-> headless RPi, without worrying about IP address, `nmap` scanning. I wanted to post it as an answer.

Where is the **canonical question** about how to directly connect a PC Windows <-> headless RPi with an Ethernet cable?

Possible candidates:

[Ethernet communication Raspberry PI and windows PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99687/ethernet-communication-raspberry-pi-and-windows-pc)

[Connect RPi to PC with direct Ethernet?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/85998/connect-rpi-to-pc-with-direct-ethernet) (closed)

[Raspberry Pi (with Static IP address) connect to PC (Windows) via Ethernet](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49709/raspberry-pi-with-static-ip-address-connect-to-pc-windows-via-ethernet)

[Connection via Ethernet to Windows](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/95460/connection-via-ethernet-to-windows)

All of them are 1 or 0-voted (and were -1-voted before).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is the best candidate:

[Ethernet communication Raspberry PI and windows PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99687/ethernet-communication-raspberry-pi-and-windows-pc)

Because it is much more succinct than the others, which tend to prattle on about irrelevant or highly localized pecularities/details.

> without worrying about IP address, nmap scanning

Most of the answers to those questions are not very good. I did not notice nmap mentioned but the idea of scanning a "network" of two computers with a direct ethernet connection is complete lunacy.

The linux side of this is a matter of blacklisting the eth interface from normal networking tools and then issuing two commands, one to put the interface up and the other to assign it an arbitrary (but valid) IP address:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/140076/5538

The routing will be done automatically by the kernel.

I've never answered the "to Windows computer" questions as I am not a Windows user, but it can't be much more difficult there.  This is definitely a sort of question where people's instincts seem to tend toward making something that is drop dead simple overly complex.

Comment: Yes this one seems a good candidate @goldilocks. I posted this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99687/ethernet-communication-raspberry-pi-and-windows-pc/140529#140529. Now I also found other answers about APIPA but not always very easy to use for a beginner.

Comment: APIPA is clever.  What if you want to connect to the Windows machine *from* the Pi though?  Is the IP of the Windows machine predictable?

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with `PiName.local`?

This does NOT require knowledge of IP addresses, scanning or anything else and also works over a network connection (although you DO have to know the `hostname` of the Pi).

It actually works with ANY network connection from almost any computer (even Windows - although some old Windoze did not support IETF networking standards).

`dhcpcd` works with a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) by default.

This has been posted as an answer numerous times including [Connecting a Computer to the Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os/37921#37921)

Comment: It works with a direct connection. Can't comment on Windows because I haven't used it for 12 years.

Comment: If you want to ask specific networking questions Meta is not the place. I don't see any inconsistency with Ingo's answer. You can **CONNECT** (which is what you asked) and use (almost) any networking tool (which obviously depends on WHAT you are trying to do). Why don't you try it?

Comment: Please note I don't discuss any networking question in my original post, but it is a *meta* question about which question is canonical about a specific topic. PS: I of course tried  many solutions over the past years (and most of them are working successfully), but it is always interesting to compare different methods.

Comment: You asked me (in a deleted comment) about Ingo's answer which is about networking tools.

Comment: Yes because you discussed some networking aspects in your answer. But all is good, we now have solved the question. Thank you for your input.